# Atributo não documentado: ForceTokenStabilizationAttribute & __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute

Tags: vb.net, .net-compiler-platform

Eu descobri um atributo **não documentado**, e ele é `Friend`, está localizado na `namespace` `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`, pois é usado no sistema, não tem nenhuma documentação. Tentei decompilar esse atributo e recebi esse source:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.[Class] Or AttributeTargets.Struct Or AttributeTargets.[Enum] Or AttributeTargets.Constructor Or AttributeTargets.Method Or AttributeTargets.[Property] Or AttributeTargets.Field Or AttributeTargets.[Event] Or AttributeTargets.[Interface]), FriendAccessAllowed()>
Friend Class FriendAccessAllowedAttribute
   Inherits Attribute

   <TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")>
   Public Sub New()
   End Sub
End Class
```

também veio essa classe, chamada `__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute`:`

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)>
Public Class __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute
   Inherits Attribute

   <TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")>
   Public Sub New()
   End Sub
End Class
```

### ambos não são documentados, mas o que são e para que servem?